# radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Hey guys I have a page with multiple radiobuttonlists and a clear selection button for each list to clear the list if pressed. The problem is with my current code if I press the clear selection button it clears all the radiobuttonlists on the page. How do I modify my code to just clear the radiobuttonlist I want. Here's a snippet of the code.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoQuestionChoice" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="Aligntext" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChoiceList_SelectedIndexChanged" />

<asp:Button ID="clearRdoQuestionChoice" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Clear Selection" OnClientClick="clearRdoQuestionChoice_ClearRadioList(); return false;" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function clearRdoQuestionChoice_ClearRadioList() {
       $("table[id$=rdoQuestionChoice] input:radio").each(function (i, x) {
           if ($(x).is(":checked")) {
               $(x).removeAttr("checked");
           }
       });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you use to make the RadioButtonList visible (right now it's hidden)

Comment: That's in my .cs class based on certain variables. I basically loop through multiple times to create various radiobuttonlists with the same id

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply changing only the selection index of radio button list? Like this ->

C# (tested)

`rdoQuestionChoice.SelectedIndex = -1`

Javascript (no tested)

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
         $("rdoQuestionChoice").checked = false;
});
```

Or you can see here for more information and other javascript functions :http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1436752

Comment: How will this be able to distinguish between the radiobuttonlists? All the radiobuttonlists on the page have the same ID

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this.

In my underlying .cs class I added the following line of code in the Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) function

```
clearRdoQuestionChoice.OnClientClick = "clearRdoQuestionChoice_ClearRadioList('" + rdoQuestionChoice.ClientID + "')";
```

In my javascript function I made the following changes

```
function clearRdoQuestionChoice_ClearRadioList(radioButtonListID) {
    var elementRef = document.getElementById(radioButtonListID);
    var inputElementArray = elementRef.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputElementArray.length; i++) {
        var inputElement = inputElementArray[i];
        inputElement.checked = false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And I changed my .aspx class to the following. I basically removed the OnClientClick attribute from asp:button

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoQuestionChoice" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="Aligntext"                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChoiceList_SelectedIndexChanged" />
<asp:Button ID="clearRdoQuestionChoice" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Clear Selection" />
```